# SQL Server Deadlock on KEY Lock when attempting to run Delete statements concurrently

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions, deadlock

I would really appreciate some help with this one. It has me stumped. Basically Im running a Proc with a series of Delete statements in a transaction. This proc will be called by a multi threaded application so lots of calls. Most of the statements are executing fine, but the final one keeps deadlocking with Key lock problems. It seems to be related to the Primary Key and the clustered index on it PK_Payloads. Ive attached all the relevant info. Thank you for any help provided.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payloads]
(
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,    
[LastProcessedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[SourceSystem] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[DestinationSystem] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
[Error] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
[ErrorDetails] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(), 
[TypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[StatusId] [smallint] NOT NULL, 
[TagId] [integer] NULL,
[EngineExecutionCrawlLocationId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[PayloadId] [bigint] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Payloads] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Payloads_W] FOREIGN KEY([TypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[W] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Payloads_X] FOREIGN KEY([StatusId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[X] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Payloads_Y] FOREIGN KEY([TagId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Y] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Payloads_Z] FOREIGN KEY([EngineExecutionCrawlLocationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Z] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Payloads_Payloads] FOREIGN KEY([PayloadId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Payloads] ([Id])
)
```

The foreign Keys also have non clustered indexes on them and there are a couple of covering non clustered indexes too.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Payloads_I5] ON [dbo].[Payloads] 
(
[Id] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Name], [StatusId]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Proc**

```
DECLARE @Details NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Details = 'Name: ' + p.[Name] + ',  Source Ref: ' + pc.[SourceContentReference] 
   + ',  Quarantine Ref: ' + ISNULL(pc.[DestinationContentReference], '')
   + ',  Archive Ref: ' + ISNULL(pc.[ArchiveContentReference], '')
FROM Payloads p
INNER JOIN PayloadContent pc ON p.[Id] = pc.[PayloadId]
WHERE p.[Id] = @PayloadId

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Audit Payload Deleted
INSERT INTO [Audit] ([AuditTypeId], [ObjectId], [Details])
VALUES (1, @PayloadId, ISNULL(@Details, ''))

DELETE FROM [A]
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId

DELETE FROM 
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId

DELETE FROM [C]
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId

DELETE FROM [D]
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId

DELETE FROM [E]
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId

DELETE FROM [F]
WHERE [PayloadContentId] IN (SELECT [Id] 
FROM [G]
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId)

DELETE FROM [G]
WHERE [PayloadId] = @PayloadId

/* Offending statement Here */
DELETE FROM [Payloads]
WHERE [Id] = @PayloadId

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Deadlock Graph**

```
<deadlock victim="process940c6088">
<process-list>
<process id="process940c6088" taskpriority="0" logused="3080" waitresource="KEY: 31:72057594041139200 (5cd3004a5da8)" waittime="2431" ownerId="85480" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.970" XDES="0x98861950" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="5432" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.970" lastbatchcompleted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.923" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CRUSADER" hostpid="2792" loginname="AIL\matt" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="85480" currentdb="31" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.DeletePayload" line="47" stmtstart="2474" stmtend="2580" sqlhandle="0x03001f00fb1c2229b2c7b7009aa000000100000000000000">
DELETE FROM [Payloads]
WHERE [Id] = @PayloadId </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 31 Object Id = 690101499] </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="process4dd048" taskpriority="0" logused="3732" waitresource="KEY: 31:72057594041139200 (a903f5656cf9)" waittime="2413" ownerId="85496" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.987" XDES="0x9724e3b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="2560" status="suspended" spid="60" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.987" lastbatchcompleted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.940" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CRUSADER" hostpid="2792" loginname="AIL\matt" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="85496" currentdb="31" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.DeletePayload" line="47" stmtstart="2474" stmtend="2580" sqlhandle="0x03001f00fb1c2229b2c7b7009aa000000100000000000000">
DELETE FROM [Payloads]
WHERE [Id] = @PayloadId </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 31 Object Id = 690101499] </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="process4c3b88" taskpriority="0" logused="3732" waitresource="KEY: 31:72057594041139200 (b6d1e11077fc)" waittime="2288" ownerId="85471" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.930" XDES="0x83925950" lockMode="S" schedulerid="3" kpid="5608" status="suspended" spid="56" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.927" lastbatchcompleted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.927" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CRUSADER" hostpid="2792" loginname="AIL\matt" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="85471" currentdb="31" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.DeletePayload" line="47" stmtstart="2474" stmtend="2580" sqlhandle="0x03001f00fb1c2229b2c7b7009aa000000100000000000000">
DELETE FROM [Payloads]
WHERE [Id] = @PayloadId </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 31 Object Id = 690101499] </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="process4dd288" taskpriority="0" logused="3732" waitresource="KEY: 31:72057594041139200 (a903f5656cf9)" waittime="2427" ownerId="85487" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.973" XDES="0x800bf950" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="2900" status="suspended" spid="59" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.973" lastbatchcompleted="2012-07-26T11:24:03.933" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CRUSADER" hostpid="2792" loginname="AIL\matt" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="85487" currentdb="31" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.DeletePayload" line="47" stmtstart="2474" stmtend="2580" sqlhandle="0x03001f00fb1c2229b2c7b7009aa000000100000000000000">
DELETE FROM [Payloads]
WHERE [Id] = @PayloadId </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 31 Object Id = 690101499] </inputbuf>
</process>
</process-list>
<resource-list>
<keylock hobtid="72057594041139200" dbid="31" objectname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.Payloads" indexname="PK_Payloads" id="lock97039400" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041139200">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process4c3b88" mode="X"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process940c6088" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
<keylock hobtid="72057594041139200" dbid="31" objectname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.Payloads" indexname="PK_Payloads" id="lock8a589900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041139200">
<owner-list/>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process4dd048" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
<keylock hobtid="72057594041139200" dbid="31" objectname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.Payloads" indexname="PK_Payloads" id="lock8a589000" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041139200">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process4dd048" mode="X"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process4c3b88" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
<keylock hobtid="72057594041139200" dbid="31" objectname="AI.DataPoint.Database.dbo.Payloads" indexname="PK_Payloads" id="lock8a589900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041139200">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process940c6088" mode="X"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process4dd288" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
</resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an index on `Payloads(PayloadID)`. Without it the FK validation has to do a table scan. This will also help all the other DELETEs but the other DELETEs as well, they are very inefficient. The other deletes don't deadlock because they *are* table scans and thus all go on the same order. The last one at least can benefit from the index on `[Id]` but in doing so it will cause conflicting order with all those scans.

Comment: Legend, thanks very much Remus.  I had thought about this a while back.  Looking at the Execution plan for the DELETE FROM Payloads I can now see it doing an Index Seek to check referential integrity instead of the scan.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Faced the similar situation , just want to share it.
Either clustered Primary key or index on the column would avoid table scan and subsequently deadlock with the referenced table